# Duvida em definir tamanho para campos de tabela!

Tags: sql-server

Olá!
Segue o seguinte código:

```
create table Pessoa (
   codigo_pessoa int not null primary key,
   nome nvarchar(50) not null,
   data_nascimento date not null,
   cpf int(11) not null
)
```

No campo de cpf, defini um tamanho para o mesmo. Entretanto, retorna o seguinte erro:
não é possível especificar uma largura de coluna no tipo de dados int.
A tipagem int, não permite definir o tamanho do campo. É assim mesmo ou tem algum erro de sintaxe?

Para resolver isso, criei a tabela dessa forma:

```
create table Pessoa (
   codigo_pessoa int not null primary key,
   nome nvarchar(50) not null,
   data_nascimento date not null,
   cpf int not null
)
```

E executei um insert nessa tabela:

```
insert into Pessoa (codigo_pessoa, nome, data_nascimento, cpf)
            values (1, 'João Silva', '20/02/1997', 03188888801);
```

Entretanto, retorna esse erro:
Erro de estouro aritmético ao converter expression no tipo de dados int.
Cpf é maior que o campo respectivo, suponho. O que acontece com esse campo de cpf? Alguém tem idéia?
Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Você pode declarar a coluna `cpf` como bigint ou como char(11). Cada opção necessita de tratamento diferente para manuseio da informação.

Comment: Como o cpf tem numeros inteiros, mas com a "mascara" tem caracteres, fiquei na duvida em qual tipo de dado, seria mais apropriado. Mas, já consegui entender como usar. Grato pela atenção!